# Detect if websocket is installed on Windows Server 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, websocket, signalr, windows-server-2012

Is there any piece of code or program via which I can confirm whether WebSocket is correctly installed on my Windows Server 2012 server

I am facing an issue with WebSocket. It is not working on Windows Server 2012. I have already installed WebSockets on my Windows Server 2012

[image]

I have already restarted the server twice.

The proof that WebSocket is not working on my server is that my following url(which Signalr uses to decide whether WebSocket is on or not)

http://abcdedf.com/signalr/default/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22myhub%22%7D%5D&_=14530662444 is returning the following response:

```
{
Url: "/signalr/default",
ConnectionToken: "xxxx",
ConnectionId: "cf63a537-ed4a-4d29-afaf-f0aec454b0c2",
KeepAliveTimeout: 6,
DisconnectTimeout: 9,
ConnectionTimeout: 110,
TryWebSockets: false,
ProtocolVersion: "1.5",
TransportConnectTimeout: 5,
LongPollDelay: 0
}
```

i.e TryWebSockets: false

The same code on which the this application is running fine on my local Windows 8 Machine. It gives

TryWebSockets: true

IIS version on Windows Server 2012 is IIS 8.5. 
My site is running under .Net Framework 4.5. 
Windows Firewall is already off there. 
In my app settings I have added this too:

```
  <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
```

In my web.config I have this too:

```
 <webSocket enabled="true"/>
```

Is there any special setting needed on Windows Server 2012 to make WebSocket working?

Is there any tool to check whether WebSocket is enabled on my Windows Server 2012 server?

Comment: FYI - that should work. I've installed SignalR on Windows Server 2012 a few times and you've found the correct role. I've never needed to tweak the `web.config` as you've suggested. Actually one difference is I've always done it on 2012 R2 - but I'm not sure how that would make a difference...

Answer (score 0):

I have often run into issues with Windows 2012 Servers caused by Internet Options in Internet Explorer since it's very restrictive.

Try opening Internet Explorer -> Internet options -> Security and tweak the settings (lower Security level for testing purposes) then go to Advanced and have a look of some of the Settings under Security that could block your sockets.

I did not run into your specific problem but whenever there is difference between Windows Server and Windows Client most of the time it's because Security restrictions that apply to Windows Server.